# Visual Studio 2010 + Resharper Tools|Options|Environment|Fonts and Colors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, color-scheme

About fonts and colors in the VS2010 C# text editor with Resharper installed.

In the following method:

```
public void Method()
     {
        var lis = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
        var exc = new System.NotImplementedException();
     }
```

ArrayList gets another color as NotImplementedException in the VS2010 text editor, because I edited the color scheme.
What would be the difference in these kinds of types so that the color scheme handles them differently?
Note that I have Resharper installed but I also tried almost all Resharper entries.

I would like to have the same color for both, but the NotImplementedException type color seems immutable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, not implemented exception is a "to do item" in resharper, Resharper->Options->Tools>Todo items. The to do item is recognized by regular expression, not by type. You can remove the todo item if you don't want implemented exception to appear in the to do list and have the same colors as other to do's. You can also change the color of todo items in general to make them the same color as type identifiers like ArrayList, Tools->Options->Environment->Font and Colors->Resharper Todo item

Comment: Correct. I used the second option, keeping the bold font setting, as a slight difference compared with other types. A regex: good to know.